# cmake file structure, how to split a CMakeLists.txt into multiple files?

Tags: cmake

Over time my CMakeLists.txt files have grown by the addition of dozens of self functions and definitions. I would like to split these into their own file so as to simplify reuse in other projects and make the CMakeLists.txt file more readable.

currently I use a superdir CMakeLists.txt but I feel there has to be a better solution then that... something similar to \input in latex? or include in c++ for that matter
Ideas?

Comment: Could "something similar to include" include [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include.html)?  :-)

Comment: Yes, :) Though googling anything + cmake and include didnt lead to that answer( for obvious reasons)

Comment: Yeah - I just added it as a comment since I thought I was maybe misunderstanding the question.  I'll stick it in as an answer which should let you close this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CMake has its own [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include.html) command which allows you to bring additional CMake code into play, with variables in the included file still in the scope of the including CMakeList file (unlike `add_subdirectory` for example).  Its effect should be as though you had pasted the contents of the included file into the CMakeList file at the point of the `include`.